# Why wont my PDF file open. ASP.net, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I'm currently trying to open a pdf file in a web browser. I am retrieving the byte array of the pdf from the DB and storing it in a application folder. From here I cant get the PDF to launch in the c# code. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i'm stumped.

```
 if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] data = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][0];
            string strFileName =   Utilities.GetAppBasePath()+Config.GetImages+DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()+".pdf";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(strFileName, data);

            OpenPDF(strFileName);
}
protected void OpenPDF(string strFileName)
    {
          Response.Redirect(strFileName);
    }
```

Comment: `From here I cant get the PDF to launch in the c# code. ` -- are you getting an exception?  It would be helpful to provide more details other than "it does not work".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if running a PDF works much like running a normal application, IF it does, then I think your best bet COULD be to use something like the lines of 'Process.Start(strFileName);' or 'Process.Start(strFileName.Text);'

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys thanks for your comments, much appreciated. There was no exception but the reason it was not work was due to a postback call. I have now put in a trigger for this to work around this. Dan, you are right it could not be called like this by response redirect and to resolve that issue I used the following code:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] data = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][0];

            OpenPDF(data);                
        }

protected void OpenPDF(byte [] data)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"image.pdf\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();            
    }
```

Thanks again for your help, apologises for any vauge-ness, im very new to posting on this site and I hope this post helps any others with this issue.

Thanks